# What events does an <input type="number" /> fire when its value is changed?

Tags: javascript, html

Just wondering whether anyone knows what events an HTML5 `<input type="number" />` element fires when its up / down arrows are clicked:

[image: example number input]

I'm already using an `onblur` for when the focus leaves the input field.

Comment: This seems to be a bug of chrome
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978087/html5-number-type-inputs-up-down-arrow-imprecise-click-bug

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`change` would be the event that is fired when the field's value changes.

I think the HTML5 event `input` would also fire.

Comment: only `oninput` is fired when 'up' and 'down' arrows are clicked.

Comment: but onchange only fires on blur, atleast in firefox. I guess we will have to look for key press.

Comment: onchange and oninput both worked in Opera, but only oninput would work in Chrome (and only then when I returned false from the event-handler - otherwise Chrome would repeatedly fire the oninput event)

Comment: @N 1.1: `oninput` IS fired when a character is insert into the field

Comment: `change` does not fire when the value is typed in, only when the buttons are clicked (at least on Firefox).

Comment: `input` is like a fusion between `keyup change`

Answer (score 41):

I found that for jQuery the following code covered keyboard input, mousewheel changes and button clicks in Chrome, and also handled keyboard input in Firefox

```
$("input[type=number]").bind('keyup input', function(){
    // handle event
});
```

Comment: Add 'change' to that too and it's perfect. You'll still want to listen for external changes to it too, and there's no harm in adding it anyway.

Comment: And also 'mousewheel' if you want to pick up on scroll events inside the input field.

Comment: Note that `.bind()` is now deprecated in favor of `.on()`

Answer (score 7):

I found that `onkeyup` and `onchange` covered everything in Chrome 19.
This handles direct value input, up down arrow keypress, clicking the buttons and scrolling the mousewheel.

`onchange` alone would be sufficient in Chrome, but other browsers that only render the field as a text box need the `onkeyup` binding, which works perfectly to read the new value.

Binding the `mousewheel` event separately was less successful. The event fired too early - before the field value was updated - and therefore always gave the field's previous value

Comment: This is also true for Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

The `onchange` event fires on blur but the `oninput` event fires as you type. Maybe you might want to put a timer on the `oninput` event and fire your `onchange` event when the user has stopped typing for a second?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [current bug in Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14678823/) preventing change or input from firing when using the arrow keys in a number input.