# onchange on date inputs

Tags: javascript, css, html, input, onchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What events does an <input type=“number” /> fire when it's value is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed)

I have a date input field

```
<input type="date" name="..">
```

In webkit and firefox, it will be added two up/down arrows on the side of the input. When clicking them, the date goes forward or backwards, but the onchange event doesn't trigger until the field loses focus. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oninput

Comment: jquery .change() might help you [http://api.jquery.com/change/](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Thanks guys, no match came up when I wrote the title. Sorry :)

Comment: I do not see the arrows in Safari 5 or Fx4 http://diveintohtml5.org/examples/input-type-date.html

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong about Fx. But in Safari I see them :)

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634412/isnt-this-html5-date-input-supposed-to-have-a-spinner-in-fx4-and-safari5/5634488#5634488

Comment: This is a great page. I do not see any support for DATE anywhere than in my Opera http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-date and on date it is a date picker - what Safari on what platform do you have a spinner on Date?

Comment: strangely enough, i have found that the change event fires differently depending on how you create it (e.g. element.onchange= ... delays firing until focus is lost, whereas element.addEventListener fires on every change)

Answer (score 3):

You could store the value in a global and check for a difference onclick.

```
<input type="date" name="myDate" id="myDate" />

var myApp = {};
myApp.myDate = "";

document.getElementById('myDate').onclick = function (e) {
    if (this.value != myApp.myDate) {
        // run onchange code

        // then set last value to current value
        myApp.myDate = this.value;
    }
};
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/ae7na/1/)

EDIT: Or, duplicate question, like comments suggest.  (See `oninput` event)