# Isn't this HTML5 date input supposed to have a spinner in Fx4 and Safari5?

Tags: html

Loading

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/examples/input-type-date.html

```
<form>
  <input name="birthday" type="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

into Fx4 and Safari5 on XPsp3, I expected to see some kind of enhancement like the up/down on type="number".

Do you?

Update: A date picker appears in Opera - nothing in Safari5 or FX4 on XP

Comment: I would have thought a date picker would be more appropriate, and as mentioned below, I think that's what Opera shows.

Comment: I agree. I was actually asking because of another question. So I was expecting to see SOMETHING but I only saw a date picker in Opera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Up" and "down" is for `type="number"`, not `type="date"`, isn't it? [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#Compatibility) suggests, that the UIs for the new types are not yet supported in anything but Opera.