# Why is this onpaste event not firing?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to capture a paste event for an `input[type="date"]` element. In Chrome you cannot copy/paste into this type of element, so as a workaround I am trying to wrap it in a `DIV` element with an `onpaste` event. The issue I'm encountering is that if you click the date input and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> nothing happens. However, if you click anywhere else in the body first and then click the date input and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it works...

```
<div onpaste="alert('test')">
    <input type="date">
</div>
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/4qh31tn0/

**EDIT:** OK, so it turns out that the `onpaste` event doesn't have to be on the `DIV`, it can be moved to the `INPUT` element, but the problem persists. If I load the jsfiddle, click the input and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, nothing happens. If I click someplace outside of the `INPUT` element beforehand then click the input and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it works...

Comment: This is beginning to look like a bug in Chrome that only affects date inputs.

Comment: Why you are not using keyup event and change date to text on dynamic and change again to  date.

Comment: Opened https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=634426

Comment: I just want to point out, though you probably already knew this, that `onpaste` isn't part of the HTML spec.  If you get this working in one browser, it's unlikely to work in another.

Answer (score 2):

While this bug (I think it's a bug) isn't fixed you can instead detect if the date input has been [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633412/onchange-on-date-inputs) using `onkeydown`, `onkeyup`, `onclick`, `onblur` and other events.

Comment: See my question again. It *does* work, but only if you have clicked someplace else on the page at least once before you try it. This is clearly a bug.

Comment: @Chris_F But that's the idea while it's a bug. If you don't want the bug happening, try to polyfill the `onchange`  event instead, as said in the answer.