# Chrome input[type=number] and onchange

Tags: events, web-applications, google-chrome, input

I have an `input[type=number]` and want an event that fires when either focus was lost and value changed (ie. `onchange`), but also I want it to fire as soon as the number arrows are clicked (retaining the focus or not).

One idea was to capture the arrow click itself: Is it possible bind event *onclick on those tiny arrows* next to numerical input? I do not want to apply onclick on the whole input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer [What events does an <input type="number" /> fire when it's value is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed)
it is suggested to use `oninput` HTML5 event, as `change` fires on blur.