# Regex replace from number type input

Tags: javascript, html, regex, web-deployment

I have a number type input that I want to prevent people from entering anything but numbers.
The examples I found work well with input type text fields but don't work well with number fields.

**Works well :)**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">
```

**Doesn't works well :(**

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')">
```

Try it for yourself on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKxFm/)

Please help...

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be `type="number"`? I think the problem here, is that the number field operates differently by nature

Comment: Also, does it really "work well"? For example if someone pastes text into the box, there is no `onkeyup` event that could catch that...

Comment: @Vasili SyrakisWell, the main reason is for it to work nicely on mobiles - like bring up the number keypad rather than the full keyboard.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - This is also true.

Comment: This might be of help in regards to which event to listen for with the type=number input field: [What events does an <input type=“number” /> fire when it's value is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed)

Comment: I wonder what the experts at http://ux.stackexchange.com/ have to say about this - is it better to silently change to user's input, to display a warning message next to the input box or to complain after the user has clicked "Submit"?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - I would imagine a bit of both.  If it were for a number field I would remove them silently but if it were for an email address I would put up an error message.

Comment: I found a pertinent question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46052/for-non-special-character-textbox-should-i-use-inline-validating-message-or-blo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just done some simple testing using JSFiddle and it would appear that if there is an invalid input on an `<input type="number" />` element then the `this.value` property is returned blank.

The following line showed this result when using Chrome:

```
<input type="number" oninput="alert(this.value)">
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tKxFm/13/)

---

In fact here's the reason why this happens:

> The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value
>   that is a valid floating-point number.
>
> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the
>   element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty
>   string instead.

^ From the [HTML5 Draft Paper section on the implementation of the number input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29)

---

This problem has taken my interest now and I've come up with a little workaround.

```
<input type="number" oninput="updateNum(this)">
```

```
function updateNum(e)
{
    e.select();
    e.value = getSelection().toString().replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
}
```

This has the potential to be buggy if the selection where to change between commands.

[JSFiddle for the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/4AAS3/1/)

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that it returns its value in Firefox but not Chrome or IE.  So it works in Firefox - is this a bug?

Comment: @JasperJohns Yep, found a bug ticket for it on Bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765772

Answer (score 1):

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4AAS3/2/) if you want to accept numbers with fractional part (3.14 for example)

```
Number: <input type="number" oninput="updateNum(this)" />

function updateNum(e) {
if (isNaN(e.value)) {
    e.value = e.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
}
```