# HTML5 "number" type inputs - up/down arrow imprecise click bug

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

Apologies for the title-gore. We discovered today that clicking near the perimeter of the "up" arrow on an HTML5 number input will trigger an event on the "up" arrow on the first click, but trigger events on the "down" arrow with every subsequent click.

Here's a one line fiddle that demonstrates the issue. I am able to reproduce the bug consistently in Chrome 59.

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Move your cursor to the top edge of the number input's "up" arrow and click several times. It may take a few tries to get the cursor in the right place. The first click will trigger the up arrow, but every subsequent click will trigger the down arrow.

Is this caused by some type of click event fuzzing done by Chrome in an effort to assist with extremely minor misclicks? I'm pretty lost here.

Note: I attempted to reproduce in Edge and Firefox but was unsuccessful. This may just need to go to the Chrome team.

Comment: I reproduced it in chrome 58.0.3029.110.  I had to first click the down arrow a few times, then click just at the upper edge of the up arrow.  A very curious bug.  Adding `style="height:100px;"` to the box made it more obvious

Comment: I ended up reproducing it on Chrome 59.0.3071.115 using Trevor's method of increasing the box height - gif [here](https://gfycat.com/MagnificentGlaringCrocodile)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there a legitimate cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. You can report it at https://bugs.chromium.org if you like.

The gist is this: The code linked to below contains logic like

```
if (is_pressed) {
    if (spin_up_pressed) {
        highlight spin up
    } else {
        highlight spin down
    }
}
```

Which is evidently not entirely correct.

https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=spin_up%7CSpinUp+f:theme&type=cs

Comment: Yes, thank you. I reported it at the time of this question. It remains unresolved. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740237