# Material-UI's TextField validation and onChange event handler don't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, onchange

I'm using **React** and **Material-UI**'s **TextField** with `type='number'` but as I saw the validation is rather simple, it just allows any character that could represent part of a number `[0-9\.eE-]*`, allowing inputs like this: `eee---...e---0.-1`, I decided to implement my own validation. *(not sure if that trivial validation is Material-UI's or HTML native, but doesn't matter anyway)*

So I wrote this regular expression for validation, but as soon as I enter a character that doesn't match my regular expression, **my *onChange* event handler doesn't get called** at all and it seems the component takes control and applies its basic validation. My event handler doesn't get called again until I correct the input and make it match with my regular expression.

**Can I prevent the component from doing this somehow?**

```
onValueChange = (ev) => {
    if( /^-?(\d+)?(\.\d*)?$/.test(ev.target.value)) {
        this.setState({ value: ev.target.value });
    }
```

Complete code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eoZOaE?editors=1000

Comment: PS: my regex allows for partial input, so it doesn't invalidate a single "-" if the user then enters "-1", in case you wondered why it doesn't really match only valid numbers.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that if I was going to apply my own validation, why not just use a plain TextField?  
That way it works. But I'd still like to know why the odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> (not sure if that trivial validation is Material-UI's or HTML native, but doesn't matter anyway)

This trivial validation is native, since Material-UI `InputBase` component only transmits `type='number'` to the native `<input />` and doesn't define any additional validations.

And seems like `onchange` event that doesn't get fired on every input - is also the behavior of native input. You can check it in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/20z5qrnqq0?fontsize=14 - as you can see - `onChange` event is also getting fired only for the 'valid' characters.

I tried to find some other solutions, with `oninput` HTML5 event, as it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed), but it doesn't work either. So in this case I think that you do the right decision with using the `type='text'` input to control all possible inputs.