# How to add an event listener to the default arrow buttons of <input type=number>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, events

```
    <input type="number" id="test">
```

Normally, to set an event listener to the entire field of <input type="number" id="test">, we can just use

```
    $("#test").on("click", function() {});
```

or

```
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {});
```

But how do I set an event listener to the two arrow buttons on the right of the input field?

[image: Input Type Number]

Does anybody know what selector to use? Or is this impossible?

Comment: just bind onchange or change event and you would get values in it. Individual click wont work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of many SO questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What events does an <input type="number" /> fire when it's value is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940258/what-events-does-an-input-type-number-fire-when-its-value-is-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use Event Listener on input type number. However, you can use ***onchange*** on the input tag.

*onchange* calls the function(myfunction in this case) each time the value is changed.

```js
function myfunction(){
        var number = document.getElementById("test");
        console.log(number.value);
    }
```

```html
    <input id="test" type="number" value="" onchange="myfunction()">
```

Comment: If there is a max and / or min on the input, `onchange` won't fire on the button click.

Comment: @Shmack exactly right. I will use `onWheel` and disregard the spinner button